# Where can one find the best explanation of the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, block

Sorry if these questions seem stupid but after a lot of research I still feel rather lost and confused !!
I understand what is bitcoin and have a fairly good understanding of the basic blockchain idea but I have a hard time understanding some concepts. 
For example where can one download the source code for the blockchain ? How did Ethereum get the source code for the blockchain ?
How can an update be "scheduled" for a specific block and not be implemented immediately ?
Or how can one code apps for a blockchain platform like ethereum ?

**I guess all these fall in the question, where can I find a thorough, complete explanation of the blockchain?**

Thanks !

Comment: We usually want questions to be specifically focussed on one topic. You are asking multiple questions, some of which are very broad. I've linked two questions that should help you find content that you seem to be interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered and I continued my research I'll post something I found online that helped me understand the blockchain.

http://blockchaindemo.io - This website visually simulates a simple blockchain to explain how it works. Pretty well made in my opinion based on comparison with other explanations I found online.

Otherwise here is the white paper from Bitcoin's creator, Satoshi Nakamoto, even if outdated, it can help understand some of the original concepts:
https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf